# MySQL: for all rows in column x containing string "foobar" place/append string "gooey" at the front

Tags: mysql

Example Before:

```
column x
yummy grains
blah blah
foobar 1
sugar daddy
foobar 2
fiber one
```

What I want after:

```
column x
yummy grains
blah blah
gooey foobar 1
sugar daddy
gooey foobar 2
fiber one
```

Comment: There's another transformation: "sugar daddy" becomes "sugar dadday" - I'm assuming that's a typo.

Comment: @Piskvor, quite right it'd be a tricky command indeed that could produce that sort of result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `yourtable` 
   SET `column x`=CONCAT('gooey ',`column x`) 
   WHERE `column x` LIKE '%foobar%';
```

Note that this is one query (as evidenced by the last `;`).

Detailed (not in the syntactically correct order):

`UPDATE yourtable` - for rows in table `yourtable`
`WHERE column x` - for those rows, where in column `column x`...
`LIKE '%foobar%'` - ...there is `foobar` somewhere in the string ([note the wildcards at both ends](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like))
`SET column x=` - set `column x` of the row to the following value:
`CONCAT('gooey ',column x)` - concatenate (add together) the literal string '`gooey`' and whatever string was in `column x`.

Comment: what would be the syntax if I wanted the same prefix on strings with 'grains'? could I simply put a comma after %foobar%, %grains%';?

Comment: @Captain Claptrap: added a token-by-token explanation. If you wanted to put the same prefix on strings with `foobar` and/or `grains`, you'd have to keep the expression syntax for `WHERE`: `WHERE column_x LIKE '%foobar%' OR column_x LIKE '%grains%'` More info on expression syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html